# Como tirar o Grayscale no css :hover

Tags: css

Olá eu coloquei uma escala em cinza em uma imagem, queria saber como tirar este efeito quando eu colocar o mouse em cima da imagem...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 .grayscale {
     background: url(yourimagehere.jpg);
     -moz-filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
     -o-filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
     -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
     filter: gray;
     filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
 }
```

Comment: Já tentou colocar "transparent" em todas as propriedades em .grayscale:hover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta assim:

```
.grayscale:hover {
   -moz-filter: initial;
   -o-filter: initial;
   -webkit-filter:initial;
   filter: initial;
}
```

Funcionando no jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/94dq2eds/5/